# SQL query gives more than one, repeated data

Tags: sql

What's wrong with this query; it gives me more than one repeated row of data

```
select (SELECT TOP(1) balanceaccount
        FROM balanceaccountmovement
        WHERE balanceaccount.CId = cr.CId 
        ORDER BY Date DESC) as kk,
        balanceaccountmovement.CId
from Customer cr 
join balanceaccountmovement
on cr.CId = balanceaccountmovement.CId
where kk > 0
```

Comment: Without knowing the data and the SQL dialect (SQL Server 2008R2, MySQL 5.5, Sybase SQL Anywhere 12, Oracle 11g, ...) it is difficullt to answer, we can just guess.

Comment: I'd have to guess that `join CariHesapHareketleri 
on cr.CId = CariHesapHareketleri.CId` is a one-to-many association.

Comment: yes one cr and many CariHesapHareketleri.

Comment: @user2460637 Please elaborate your requirement !!

Comment: @FrankPI I think TOP(1) is a SQL Server thing...but you're right...preferable to tag the question correctly instead of guessing what :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that it's SQL Server since you used TOP(1) :

```
SELECT bam.balanceaccount, bam.CId
FROM Customer cr 
JOIN balanceaccountmovement bam ON bam.CId = cr.id
     AND bam.balanceaccount > 0
     AND Date = (SELECT TOP(1) date 
                 FROM balanceaccountmovement bam2 
                 WHERE bam.CId = bam2.CId
                 ORDER BY date DESC)
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a2bec/2/0

Comment: yes I jus adding AND bam.balanceaccount > 0 to your query ,but u already did.thank you so much fabien,

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more about your data?

Just looking at the query, I think that a "Group By" will help.

Also, You're only doing a "SELECT TOP(1)" for the subquery.  You may want to do this for the encompassing SELECT as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont think gruop by works fine.I am getting the last data inserted inside CariHesapHareketleri  using  ORDER BY Trh(date) DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (SELECT TOP(1) CariBakiye   FROM 
                        CariHesapHareketleri 
                    where   CId= cr.CId ORDER BY Trh DESC

                     ) as kk,    CariHesapHareketleri.CId  from
                    Cari cr
```

See You are selection `Top(1)` cariBakiye but what about CId  ??
Well look at this way try to execute only this much of your query (after removing joins and Alias) ,You will get repeated CariBakiye and All Cid values

[image: Something like this]

So your query is wrong here.
Can you elaborate your requirement please .

---

```
select TOP(1) (SELECT TOP(1) CariBakiye   FROM 
                        CariHesapHareketleri 
                    where   CId= cr.CId ORDER BY Trh DESC

                     ) as kk,    CariHesapHareketleri.CId  from
                    Cari cr 
                    join CariHesapHareketleri   on cr.CId=CariHesapHareketleri.CId
                 where kk > 0
```

---

```
select balanceaccount,(SELECT TOP(1) balanceaccount
        FROM balanceaccountmovement
        WHERE balanceaccount.CId = cr.CId 
        ORDER BY Date DESC) as kk,
        balanceaccountmovement.CId
from Customer cr 
join balanceaccountmovement
on cr.CId = balanceaccountmovement.CId
where kk > 0
```

Try this you will see that you are not getting repeated data , but how `sql` repersent that data to you ? So use `TOP` clause in your main query too.

-Hope i am in right direction .If not please let me know

Comment: one cr and many CariHesapHareketleri,I am getting last recored data from CariHesapHareketleri  and the data related to the    Cari

Comment: @user2460637 See your query is not wrong its right but according to your requirement its not right , Question is what you want to fetch ?? If you want a single value then use `TOP` clause on main query level also Check the updated answer if it helps.

Comment: @user2460637 See you have Top(1)CariBakiye  from sub query but how you can relate it with multiple values ?Thats why you are getting multiple values because your inner join fetches all data which is related on both table on the basis on `CId` value and puts in front of TOP(1)CariBakiye  , Try putting your balanceaccount in outer query like i did in my answer you will get to know that in actual your query fetching all data but it does not have fields to represent so you are getting such repeated data  which is actually not repeated but represented as such.